# Possible faults for significant kVA differences in switch cabinets?

Tags: power, transformer, switches

Would there be any faults if any on the cables, either nearby or near the switch cabinet if there is a significant kVA difference say 2x-3x? For example, for 3 phase wiring, 2 cables having 1000 kVA and 1 cable having 500 kVA? Would long pulls with multiple splice boxes be affected by this? Just to be specific, the application is for overhead or underground designs of electrical networks for housing districts.

Comment: I believe the words you're looking for are "phase imbalance"

Comment: Thanks, pretty useful information. Would still be interesting to know that specific KVA difference, maybe someone made this type of electrical network in the past